# will converting from dateFrom/dateTo to period data type improve performance?

Tags: teradata, period

I have a really slow query and I'm trying to speed it up.

I have a target date range (dateFrom/dateTo) defined in a table with only one row I need to use as a limit against a table with millions of rows.  Is there a best practice for this?

I started with one table with one row with dateFrom and dateTo fields.  I can limit the rows in the large table by `CROSS JOIN`ing it with the small table and using the `WHERE` clause, like:

```
select
  count(*)
from
  tblOneRow o, tblBig b
where
  o.dateFrom < b.dateTo and
  o.dateTo >= b.dateFrom
```

or I can `inner join` the tables on the date range, like:

```
select
  count(*)
from
  tblOneRow o inner join 
  tblBig b on
    o.dateFrom < b.dateTo and
    o.dateTo >= b.dateFrom
```

but I thought if I changed my single-row table to use one field with a `PERIOD` data type instead of two fields with `DATE` data types, it could improve the performance.  Is this a reasonable assumption?  The explain isn't showing a time difference if I change it to:

```
select
  count(*)
from
  tblOneRow o inner join 
  tblBig b on
    begin(o.date) < b.dateTo and
    end(o.date) >= b.dateFrom
```

or if I convert the small table's date range to a `PERIOD` data type and join `ON P_INTERSECT`, like:

```
select
  count(*)
from
  tblOneRow o inner join 
  tblBig b on
    o.date p_intersect period(b.dateFrom, b.dateTo + 1) is not null
```

to help the parsing engine with this join, would I need to define the fields on the large table with a period data type instead of two dates?  I can't do that as I don't own that table, but if that's the case, I'll give up on improving performance with this method.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't expect any difference between the first three Selects, Explain should be the same a `product join` (the optimizer should expect exactly one row, but as it's duplicated the estimated size should be the number of AMPs in your system). The last Select should be worse, because you apply a calculation (`OVERLAPS` would be more appropriate, but probably not better).

One way to improve this single row cross join would be a View (`select date '...' as dateFrom, date '...' as dateTo`) instead of the single row table. This should resolve the dates and result in hard-coded dateFrom/To instead of a product join.

Similar when you switch to Scalar Subqueries:

```
select
  count(*)
from
  tblBig b
where
  (select min(o.dateFrom) from tblOneRow)  < b.dateTo
 and
  (select min(o.dateTo) from tblOneRow) >= b.dateFrom
```

Comment: thx, Dieter.  Not sure how to avoid my full table scan, plus there's 800 rows with dateTo > dateFrom, would need extra code to avoid that condition in a period function.  So converting from 2 date fields to a period field won't improve performance?

Comment: @Beth: No, a Period is the same as two seperate columns with an additional check: `dateFrom < dateTo`